# jQuery - Add/Remove class based on selected item in list

Tags: jquery

I have a very basic list in HTML:

```
<ul id="thumbselector">
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/80/80"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/81/81"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/81/81"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/82/82"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/81/82"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/80/80"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/81/81"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/81/81"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/82/82"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/81/82"/></li>                            
</ul>
```

Then im using toggleClass to add an .active class to the img when its clicked:

```
$('#thumbselector img').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

However I want each of the images to be aware of each other, so when I select one image and give it the .active class - If I then select another image I want to make sure any previous image with the .active class has it removed.

Any ideas?

Comment: your wonderful placeholder kitten site isn't working as described!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just remove the active class from all of them first instead? :

```
$('#thumbselector img').click(function() {
  $('#thumbselector img').removeClass('active');    
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoo

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$('#foo').toggleClass(className, addOrRemove);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (addOrRemove) {
    $('#foo').addClass(className);
  }
  else {
    $('#foo').removeClass(className);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#thumbselector img').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#thumbselector img').click(function() {
  $('#thumbselector .active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fermin/5JAUh/

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the class from all sibling elements:

```
$('#thumbselector img').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvhWD/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the LIVE with click not just CLICK since you are dynamically adding/removing a class. See my example:

```
$('#thumbselector img').live('click', function() {
  $('#thumbselector img').removeClass('active');    
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Actually, you CAN use just click, but you need to wrap it in docready: `$(function() { //code });` or add it after the mark up

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for this problem:

```
$('#thumbselector img').on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```