# Active & Inactive class add & remove

Tags: jquery, addclass, toggleclass

I need to add & remove class on click of anchor tag.

```
 <div class="activeTab">
    <a href="#." class="active">Active</a>
    <a href="#.">Inactive</a>
</div>
```

Above div has two anchor tags & "Active" & "Inactive" one has a class 'active'. my requirement is need to remove that 'active' class on click of  "Inactive" anchor tag & add the class 'active' to that clicked "Inactive" anchor and if I clicked on "Active" anchor again the class will remove form "Inactive" anchor & will add to the "Active" anchor. with jquery.

Comment: I have used if else condition to

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Add active class to main menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607480/jquery-add-active-class-to-main-menu)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883642/jquery-add-remove-class-based-on-selected-item-in-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245934/jquery-add-remove-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i undestood well...

I made a refork of an old lil snippet doing what you want (or what i guess you want) xDD

Sorry by my english, it's hard to me write on it.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="activeTab">
      <a href="#." class="button_active">Active</a>
      <a href="#." class="button_inactive">Inactive</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.activeTab { width:100%; padding:30px 0 20px 0; background:#fff; } 
.active { background: #f0f0f0; }
```

JS

```
$(function() { $( ".button_active" ).click(function() {

$( ".activeTab" ).addClass("active");

return false; }); });

$(function() { $( ".button_inactive" ).click(function() {

$( ".activeTab" ).removeClass("active");

return false; }); });
```

You can see a working demo on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aritz81/74bGe/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.activeTab a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('div.activeTab a').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
   $this.siblings().removeClass();
   if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
      $this.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive')
   } else {
      $this.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
  }

})
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XwMbx/1/)

Comment: on click inactive class is not added to the inactive anchor